# How can Spark in yarn recover from an executor loss with RDD persisted on disk

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I prepared some RDD and compute it for a few hours. I use YARN. Sometimes executors get lost and spark (1.6) goes crazy as it misses source data.
Seems that persist(DISK) can help me in this situation.

But I wonder, as persist on disk uses a non-dfs place to store the data, how can remote executors read it? Or is the computation stuck until YARN can schedule an executor to a particular node?

Maybe I use the wrong mechanism and rdd.checkpoint(hdfs://) is more appropriate here?

Comment: I believe, jobs will be re-launched and it will re-execute from stage1.

Comment: @BalajiReddy, I speak about the case when AM and driver still alive, so job is expected to be reliable enough not to be fully restarted

Answer (score 0):

So I've chosen checkpointing after all.

As I understood, cache has only speedup goal for the further iterations, but not the reliability ones. For example, with the property `spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout` data can even be removed at some point.

Based on the documentation 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#graceful-decommission-of-executors After removing an executor, its cached data can't be reached, although "spark shuffle service" is available on the host (it serves another purpose).

Checkpointing seems to work fine.